# debugging module - line and line in included files

Tags: php, debugging

Elsewhere than where you read/write to mysql is it useful to do some debugging?

I neither can't figure out how to get the exact line and line in the included/required files where the "error" exists to determine where to look for the "error"?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking... :-|

Comment: What level is your error reporting set to?  Are you not getting standard error messages displayed?  Are you talking about mysql errors or php errors?

Comment: show your code on where  u have an error

Comment: you mean, you have files with bunch of includes and you can't trace where in those file is the error?

Comment: I don't have any code.. I'm just wondering how you can locate an error if you have included/required alot of files?

Comment: use xDebug. it will show not only the error but a call stack.

Answer (score 0):

consider installing [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) for a much wider error reporting, including stack traces